# how do I make my git project visible to GitHub?

Tags: git, github

I have a git login where I have a project that I want to migrate to GitHub. This will allow tested changes to be automatically deployed to Heroku. I'm away from home and trying to get this done on an a
Android tablet. I've installed OpenHub and can see my GitHub repositories but can't access the git repo. I'm not able to clone the git repo to the Android device.

Any ideas welcome.

Comment: Try the [project importer](https://help.github.com/en/articles/importing-a-repository-with-github-importer) perhaps?

Comment: Can you copy the repositories from the server to your device using `scp` or similar? Then they can be uploaded.